# Python: How do I output my float values with two digits after the decimal with new .format()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, formatting

I'm teaching myself some Python for a job opportunity. I've just started, and I can't seem to reconcile how one uses print"".format() to output floats with only two digits after the decimal.

I've tried putting .2f in different places; no luck.

This is what I have:

```
def displayEmployeeData(self):
    print "Name: {:<10} ID: {:<10} Team: {:<10} salary: ${:<10} tenure: {:<10} months".format(self.name, self.ID, self.team, self.salary, self.tenure)
```

Comment: use this `{:.2f}`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it follows the format

```
print '{arg_num: format} string".format(<tuple of args>)
```

So in your case, it would be like:

```
def displayEmployeeData(self):
    print "Name: {0} ID: {1} Team: {2} salary: ${3:.2f} tenure: {4} months".format(self.name, self.ID, self.team, self.salary, self.tenure)
```

Comment: What if I already have the {:<10} in there already? Would I do {:<10.2f} or something similar?

Answer (score 1):

You need to use `{0:.xf}` where 0 is the argument number and x is the number of digits you want.

```
>>> print "{0:.3f} something".format(2.234234239)
>>> 2.234 something
```

Please go through the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html) for more formatting details.

Comment: What if I already have {:<10} there? Do I put .3f in front, after?

Comment: You can use `{0:<10.3f}` in that case.

Answer (score 1):

You have these two ways:

```
print("{0:.3f} something".format(2.234234239))
print("{0:<10.3f} something".format(2.234234239))
```

or, alternatively:

```
data = 2.234234239
print(f"{data:.3f} something")
print(f"{data:<10.3f} something")
```

#### outputs:

```
2.234 something
2.234      something
```

Comment: I already have my :<10 in there. Would I precede the <10, proceed it, or do something else? Thanks!

Comment: see edits to the answer.